# Scrapy - Dynamic file naming form parsed item

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm working on scraping program for an art museum.
I'm new to the Scrapy framework and intermediate in python at best
I need to download images from the website and name them accordingly with the value form the parsed data.
I've been going through Scrapy documentation and Google searches but no luck so far. I'm stuck at the pipeline.
I know how I could fix file names after running the Scrapy with wrapper program, but that seem counter productive and sloppy.

Each item yielded from the spider looks like this:

```
{'Artist': 'SomeArtist',
 ...
 'Image Url': 'https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/media/33219/n-1171-00-000049-hd.jpg',
 'Inventory number': 'NG1171'}
```

I need to name the image by `'Inventory number'`

I managed to make a custom pipeline, but no luck making it work the way I want to.
The closest I got was this, but it failed miserably by assigning same `self.file_name` value to many images

```py
class DownloadPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
         def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
             # The only point, that I've found, for accessing item dict before downloading
             self.file_name = item['Inventory number']
             yield Request(item["Image Url"])
    
         def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
             return f"Images/{self.file_name}.jpg"
```

Something like this would be great:

```py
class DownloadPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    
         def file_path(self, request, item, response=None, info=None):
             file_name = item['Inventory number']
             return f"Images/{file_name}.jpg"
```

Is there any way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you yield the request in `get_media_requests` you can pass arbitrary data inside the meta param, so you can access as an attribute of request in your `file_path` method.

```
class DownloadPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        yield Request(
            url=item["Image Url"],
            meta={'inventory_number': item.get('Inventory number')}
        )
    
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        file_name = request.meta.get('inventory_number)
        return f"Images/{file_name}.jpg"
```

[Read more here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta)

Comment: Great thinking! I wouldn't have come up with that.
This solves my problem!
Though one minor fix is needed:
Your solution didn't work initially and while debugging
`response.meta raised`:
`*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'meta'`
However `request` had the metadata needed so just changing `response` to `request` did the trick
Thank you very much once again!

Comment: Nice catch. As I'm very used to get the `meta` in callback functions I just typed `response`, but as you noticed the pipeline handles the request, so that's where you will find the attribute. Just fixed.